# Google Maps API (JS) InfoWindow issue showing up images (html <img> tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm making a tiny web app with Google Maps API (JavaScript), in my app I have a for to loop through locations (latitude and longitude) an some other information... Into the for I have this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    var coords =  new google.maps.LatLng(Number(locations[i][1]), Number(locations[i][2]))
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map
    });

    var iwcontent="<a href='app.php?id="+locations[i][3]+"' target='_blank'><h4><img='images/icons/"+locations[i][3]+"/logo.jpg' class='minilogo'> "+locations[i][0]+"</h4></a>";
    console.log(iwcontent);
    bounds.extend(coords);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(iwcontent);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
```

In the console I recieve correct HTML structures (imho), like this:

```
<a href='app.php?id=ABCD-J2WZSW' target='_blank'><h4><img='images/icons/ABCD-J2WZSW/logo.jpg' class='minilogo'> ABCD, 33.</h4></a>
```

**in4b:** the file `images/icons/ABCD-J2WZSW/logo.jpg` exists and `.minilogo` class have a fixed (visible) `width` css value.

**The problem/issue is:** I don't see any image!

**Interesting:** If I "inspect" the infoWindow, I can see the following:

```
<a href="app.php?id=ABCD-J2WZSW" target="_blank"><h4><img='images icons="" abcd-j2wzsw="" logo.jpg'="" class="minilogo"> ABCD, 33.</img='images></h4></a>
```

Please note:

1. The  tag is totally messed up!
2. In the  tag the id value is lowercase.

*Why this happens? How can I fix it?* Thanks for reading, and please forgive my bad english!

Comment: Provide a working fiddle of your code?

Comment: is complex to replicate all of that code... I have explained the issue and the code (with DOM inspection too).

Comment: All the markers are well setted, the infowindows show the text but not the images. For some weird reason, the `<img>` is rendered in this way: `<img='images icons="" abcd-j2wzsw="" logo.jpg'="" class="minilogo"> ABCD, 33.</img='images>`

Comment: How one can regenerate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with creating your `img` tag. In your code, you cannot assign a url value to `img`, its assigned to the `src` attribute. Here is your `img` tag code in the wrong format - `<img='images/icons/"+locations[i][3]+"/logo.jpg' class='minilogo'>`, and since there is no `src` attribute the whole HTML structure is getting messed up.

It should be -

```
<img src='images/icons/"+locations[i][3]+"/logo.jpg' class='minilogo'>
```

That should take care of your issue!